# Why store is not called?

Tags: php, laravel-4

Although I have defined the route of scrud methods for my controller like this:

```
Route::resource('widgets', 'WidgetsController');
```

When I create a new widget, the `store` method will not be called, the `index` method is called instead

The form for creating a new widget is straight forward:

```
{{ Form::open(array('class'=>"form-horizontal" , 'url' => 'widgets','files'=>true)) }}
    <fieldset>

        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>Add new widget </legend>




        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('title', 'Title',array('class' => "col-md-4 control-label"))}}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {{Form::text('title', '')}}
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('file','Choose widget zip file',array('class' => "col-md-4 control-label", 'id'=>'')) }}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {{ Form::file('file','',array('id'=>'','class'=>'input-file')) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton">Create widget</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </fieldset>
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not define any `submit` button.

Add `type="submit"` to your upload button or use Laravel `Form::submit("Upload")` helper

```
    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton">Create widget</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
           {{ Form::submit('Upload', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
        </div>
    </div>
```